# JPA 2.0 IdClass field name mapping

Tags: jpa

I have an Entity and a related IdClass.

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(MyEntityId.class)
class MyEntity {
    @Id @ManyToOne You you; <---------------------|
    @Id @ManyToOne He he; ------------------------+---------|
}                                                 |         |
                                                  | @@?     |
class MyEntityId {                                |         | @@?
    Long you; <-----------------------------------|         |
    Long he; <----------------------------------------------|
}
```

Is it OK without any `MapsId` or something?
Does JPA automatically maps **`you`** to **`you`** and **`he`** to **`he`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types must match. I.e. they should be `Long` in  your entity. Apart from that - yes, they are matched by name.

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't JPA 2.0 make it possible to annotate `@Id` directly onto `@ManyToOne`? [Example JPA 2.0 ManyToOne id annotation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Example_JPA_2.0_ManyToOne_id_annotation)